# Is there a way to randomly generate groups of numbers so that each number is repeated the same amount of times but only in any given group once?

Tags: python

Sorry for the long title, but I'm not sure how to shorten it. I'm trying to program an object that targets other objects. Each object is assigned an integer id starting from 0, and that's all that's really relavent here. I can access objects by id, so I jsut need to get the numbers. Each object should target the same amount of other objects, not target itself, and not target any other object more than once. I want to make each object randomly choose it's targets given these conditions, which is trivial. But this can make thing uneven, which I want to avoid. By uneven, I mean the amount of times an object is targeted by other objects is random. So what I want is for each object to not only have the same amount of targets, but be *targeted* the same amount of times, which would end up being the same amount. This leads to my problem. I need to ranomly generate groups of numbers from a given range. Each group will be the same size. Within each group, each number is unique. The order is irrelevent; these groups could just be sets. Overall, each number  should appear the same mount of times. The amount of times each number is repeated and the size of the groups is the same, and given. Making sure each object's id isn't in the corresponding group can be done after the groups are generated, so that's not an issue.

---

### Attempt 1: Guess and check

So my first thought was a simple guess-and-check method. Basically just randomly generating the groups of numbers and rejecting invalid numbers. Ignoring that this program sometimes ends up in an infinite loop (this was just a quick thing made for this), it gets the job done. But I feel like it's kinda inefficent, and there's still the whole infinite loop problem.

```
import random
from typing import Tuple, Set, Iterator

def randTargets(numObjs:int, numTargets:int) -> Iterator[Tuple[int, Set[int]]]:
    # numObjs is the total number of objects

    # numTargets is the number of other objects each object will target
    # numTargets can be assumed to be in the range [2, numObjs)
    numLeft = [numTargets] * numObjs
    # numLeft represents how many times each object can be targeted
    # i.e., if numLeft[i] is n, i can only be targeted n more time(s)
    
    for i in range(numObjs):
        targets = set()
        # this can get caught in an infinite loop where the only
        # target left is the object itself, but I'm too lazy to fix
        # that right now. Just assume that doesn't happen lmao
        
        while len(targets) < numTargets:
            t = random.randrange(numObjs)
            # checks that the target isn't the object itself, hasn't already
            # been targeted too many times, and hasn't already been targeted
            # by this item
            if t != i and numLeft[t] > 0 and t not in targets:
                targets.add(t)
                numLeft[t] -= 1
        yield i, targets
        
    # check to make sure every object has been targeted exactly numTargets times
    assert all(i == 0 for i in numLeft)
```

---

### Attempt 2: Not really random

I tried to take a crack at this, but the best thing I could come up with wasn't exactly random.

```
def randTargetsSlightlyBetter(numObjs:int, numTargets:int) -> Iterator[Tuple[int, Set[int]]]:
    # numObjs is the total number of objects
    # numTargets is the number of other objects each object will target
    # numTargets can be assumed to be in the range [2, numObjs)
    objs = list(range(numObjs))
    targets = []
    
    for offset in random.sample(range(1, numObjs), k=numTargets):
        # shifts the objs list to the right by offset, wrapping around
        targets.append(objs[offset:] + objs[:offset])

    for obj, *targets in zip(objs, *targets):
        yield obj, targets
```

I feel like it might be kinda hard to tell what that does, so here:

```
# if numObjs = 4, objs looks like this:
[0, 1, 2, 3]
# let's assume instead of random offsets I just use (1, 2)
# targets would look like this:
[[1, 2, 3, 0],
 [2, 3, 0, 1]]
# adding objs to the beginning of targets would get:
[[0, 1, 2, 3],
 [1, 2, 3, 0],
 [2, 3, 0, 1]]
# each column is a group, the first row being the object targeting the others
# transposing the list using zip(*targets), we get:
[(0, 1, 2),
 (1, 2, 3),
 (2, 3, 0),
 (3, 0, 1)]
# which would be equivalent to zip(objs, *targets)
```

Trying to randomize this by shuffling the values of the inital list `objs` wouldn't do anything, because the individual objects are interchangable and the ids are arbitrary. So I thought to randomize how much the target lists are offset, which kind works. But this wouldn't be completely random, there would still be a pattern to things. Looking at the example with offsets of `(1, 2)`, we can see that object `0` would target objects `1` and `2`. Object `1` would target `2` and `3`, and so on. While the pattern would be harder to see with randomized offsets, there still would be one, and that's what I'm trying to avoid.
Sorry if any of this was confusingly explained, I can have a wierd way of thinking about thing lmao. If anything needs clarifying, let me know.

---

### TL;DR:

I have a range of integer numbers, and I want to randomly generate groups of numbers from this range in a way that no number appears more than once in any given group. The order of numbers in a group doesn't matter, and groups don't have to have every number, just a certain amount. Additionally, I want to do this so that overall, every number in the range appears multiple times between all the groups.

---

### Example output:

```
>>>randGroups(range(4), repeats=2)
[{0, 2}, {1, 3}, {0, 3}, {1, 2}]
>>>randGroups(range(10), repeats=3)
[{1, 8, 9}, {1, 2, 8}, {5, 6, 7}, {2, 3, 6}, {4, 5, 9}, {5, 7, 9}, {0, 8, 9}, {0, 2, 8}, {1, 6, 7}, {0, 3, 4}]
```

Comment: Maybe add a TLDR for us simpler folk?

Comment: Oh yeah, probably should do that lmao. I'll add one

Answer (score 0):

Randomized via index as opposed to actual parameter, while it isn't the most random it might still count.

```py
# import library
import random

# input parameters
range_ = 9
repeats = 4

# rotate array elements
def rotate(input, n):
    return input[n:] + input[:n]

# shifts for shuffleing, as they are all different then no index can have same element
shifts = [i for i in range(0,range_)]
random.shuffle(shifts)

# arrays to partition for shuffling
to_shuffle = [[j for j in range(0,range_)] for i in range(0,repeats)]

# rotate arrays relative to shift
for i in range(0,repeats):
    temp = rotate(to_shuffle[i],shifts[i])
    to_shuffle[i] = temp

# exchange rows and columns so as to give proper output
output_arrays = [[to_shuffle[j][i] for j in range(0,repeats)] for i in range(0,range_)]

# random output
print(output_arrays)
```

Example output:

```
[[3, 8, 4, 5], [4, 0, 5, 6], [5, 1, 6, 7], [6, 2, 7, 8], [7, 3, 8, 0], [8, 4, 0, 1], [0, 5, 1, 2], [1, 6, 2, 3], [2, 7, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this is functionally the same thing that I tried to do on my second attempt. The problem is that it isn't exactly random, but I want it to be as random as possible.

Comment: Oh, just noticed that, sorry. The only way to really do it would be a hard problem (seeing that you'd have to check the arrays other values) , additionally there'd always be an element of non-randomness seeing that each value would be dependent on the values of the other arrays. I have an idea as to how to do this but it would be ugly and inefficient. Best of luck to you!